# Unequal spacing issue with pre-existing UI elements

Tags: search, interface, style-guide

I'm using a style guide to redesign my company's home page but the search bar is too large to fit in the original place I envisioned.

To fix this issue, I moved the search bar upward, but that created awkward negative space to the left of it. To fix that issue, I filled in the negative space with a red information box to emphasize some selling points.

[image]

Is this a poor use of this type of UI element? My gut is telling me that I should include a "close" option, but then I'd be back to square one with the spacing issue as soon as the user closes it.

Does anybody have another suggestion or comment to improve my current idea? Thanks.

p.s. This is my first question, please let me know if it is inappropriate in any way.

Comment: Any particular reason for not placing the search input in the "first/second row" of the site, as in amazon, facebook, etc?

Comment: @rewobs That's not a bad idea! The search bar element was given to me in a particular size and it was also on the right side in the other new page layouts (http://www.thinkvacuums.com/central-vacuum/). However, I don't see any reason why I can't make it different in size/placement on the home page...

Comment: Mmm I think you should propose some redesign, the page is quite overloaded and results overwhelming. I think you/your team should think what thinks should be in the mage page and remove the others. E.g: The brands bar is quite unnecessary for me and moreover the way it's implemented. The border of the middle have too much shadow. You're using to many colors, dark grey, other dark gray, yelow, red, blue, green, other green, light red, dark red, etc.

Comment: @rewobs Completely agreed. This page was created way before I worked here. I've proposed redesign many times, but unfortunately the boss man isn't the most open minded person. On the bright side though, your search bar idea worked. Is there a way to mark your comment as "answered"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that this an e-commerce website it'd be very recommendable to **give the search field more presence** since it's very likely that **the users will try to search for an specific product** **before starting the navegation through categories** or other means that your site provide. Additionally **be sure that the search works as expected**, because in other cause the user could think the store just doesn't have that product and leave it, which is the last thing you want.

**A good position to place it would be the top** of your website where it'll be a much more scannable position and will encourage the user to use. Also a bigger size would help.

Most used e-commerce and mass-content websites usually **locate the search field in the first or second "row"** of the layout. E.g.: Amazon, eBay, Aliexpress, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo, etc. If you want to give it even more visibility you can place it over a darker background (as in Facebook). Follow this kind of convention will help the users to feel more familiar with your site.

Answer (score 2):

It's rarely a good idea to make up meaningful (non-decorative) UI elements just to balance out the screen. The point is usually to remove stuff, not to add stuff :). This is for all kinds of reasons - cognitive load, visual clutter, focusing the user on what matters etc.

As to the problem at hand, you can tackle it in a number of ways. The important thing is to understand just how important search is to your website. If it's a large e-commerce site with a huge inventory, then search would be very important. In that case it probably deserves the space that you allocated to the information box - it can be very large. E.g. Amazon, Facebook, Google Play, LinkedIn.

If it's really not that important, you can cut it down to just the search icon and display the field only when the icon is pressed. There's a major site that does this, but I don't remember which right now.

If it's not hugely important but still too important to reduce it to an icon, you can incorporate the button within the search field, so instead of a button saying "search" and taking up some real estate there's just the icon that can be pressed.

Recently it's become common to lose the search button even if the search only happens on submit (which is bad practice in my opinion). It relies on the user knowing that they must hit Enter for the search to begin. That's the way it works on this site. It can save you enough real estate to get the search bar into that sidebar.

Comment: I thought of the same thing actually. It would solve my problem, but that search bar is part of the style guide that I have to follow.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution regarding the replacement of the red info with something more appropriate or possibly a solution regarding a slight layout change..